# Strange BoxCutter behaviour

Tags: modeling, add-on

This happens only in one file which admittedly is getting a bit complicated. I select object to be cut, then the cutting option ( Box or whatever ). When I drag across the object selected, it deselects and nothing happens?

Anybody else had this?

Blender 3.6 on Mac M1 with OS 14 ( Sonoma )

Comment: Hi. Since BoxCutter is a third-party addon this question will probably be closed. You should have a look at the documentation page at https://boxcutter-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/  and if somewhere in there you don't find a solution, you should contact the developer.

Comment: No problem.
Sorted by removing buildup of cutters. Now working fine.